# Why is the cookie not sent on first request until second request in nextAuth

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies, next.js

I am experiencing a confusing situation here. I am using Nextjs to build application and implemented authentication with NextAUth. I have a custom login api which returns an `access token` and `refresh token`. The `refresh token` was set as cookie and I wanted to refresh the token and generate a new `access token` when the access token expires. Strangely, each time I make a request that needs to check the cookie for the `refresh token` before generating a new `access token`, the first request has no cookie. I mean, I won't be able to see cookie as part of the request sent back to my server. The second time I make the same request, the cookie would be part of the request sent back. If I repeat the same request again, the cookie would be empty again and on another repeat, it would be available.
This means, on each first request, the cookie is always empty and returns the cookie on second request. What could be wrong? This is how I set the cookie in backend. I am using nodejs and expressjs.

```
 const userRefreshToken = JWTRefresh(user?.id);

        res.cookie('refreshJWT', userRefreshToken, {
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 604800000,
        } )
```

On the Nextjs app via NextAuth, I handled the login request like this:

```
type NextAuthOptionsCallback = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => NextAuthOptions

const nextAuthOptions: NextAuthOptionsCallback = (req, res) => {

return{
session: {
  strategy: "jwt",
 },
 providers:[
  CredentialsProvider({
      type: "credentials",
      credentials: {},

     async authorize(credentials, req){
          const { username, password } = credentials as {
              username: string;
              password: string;
            };

            if(!credentials){
              return null
            }
            const userData = {
              username: username,
              password: password
            }
          

            try {
              
              const response = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/login`, userData);
              if(response?.data){
                
                const user: jwtDecodedAttributes = jwt_decode(response?.data?.userToken);
                
                
                //const cookies = response.headers['set-cookie']

                //res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookies as string[])
               
                return {
                  id: user.userId,
                  name: user.username,
                  role: user.role,
                  profilepicture: user.profilepicture,
                  iat: user?.iat,
                  exp: user?.exp,
                  username: user?.username,
                  token: response?.data?.userToken,
                  email: user.email,
                  userId: user?.userId,
                  refresh: response?.data.userRefreshToken
                };
          }
           
              
            } catch (error) {
              
              
            }
            return null
      }
   })
   ,

   pages: {
  signIn: "/login",

  },

  callbacks:{
  async jwt({token, user, trigger, session}){
     if (trigger === "update") {
    return { ...token, ...session.user };
  }
    return {...token, ...user} ;
  },

  async session({session, token, user}){
  
  session.user = token
 
  
  return session
 }
 
 }

 };


 export default (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
 return NextAuth(req, res, nextAuthOptions(req, res))
 }
```

On each API request via `axios`, the cookie is supposed to be seen by my backend but I get to see it only on the second request after the first goes through and returns an empty cookie. Basically, the cookie object is empty on every first request.